# Get plural version of Rails model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have an ActiveRecord model called `PaymentMilestone`.

Is there a good way to get `payment_milestones` out of that?

(I know `#table_name` can kind of do that, but my table name is `payment_milestone` (singular), not `payment_milestones`, and I need the plural version.)

Comment: For what reason do you want the plural name?  Would `PaymentMilestone.model_name.collection` be a better option?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A few method calls, but this works:

```
> PaymentMilestone.name.underscore.pluralize
=> "payment_milestones"
```

Answer (score 21):

`PaymentMilestone.model_name.plural`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `Model.model_name` returns a Returns an `ActiveModel::Name`, and responds to `singular`, `plural` and other useful methods. Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-i-model_name

Comment: I appreciate the question is asking for the plural name, but depending on the reason for getting the name, perhaps `PaymentMilestone.model_name.collection` might be a better option?

Comment: Sure, that would work perfectly. This would be basically the same solution as suggested by @user2069311 by the way (`PaymentModel.name.tableize`) since `#collection` is basically this: `ActiveSupport::Inflector.tableize(@name)`.

Answer (score 3):

```rb
>PaymentModel.name.tableize 
=> "payment_milestones"
```

One fewer call, and more transparent, than the current accepted answer (`PaymentModel.name.tableize`).